# Access test results in rspec after(:suite)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I currently collect output of several thousand rspec examples in a log file, when there's a failure I parse output and send out various notifications.

I'd like to get rid of this old code and do it in a more civilized manner, eg, in an after(:suite) block if I could access an array of the examples that failed I could then send my notifications.

So how do I get an array of examples that failed in an after(:suite) block?

Comment: Hi Nick, Im attempting to achieve this now, did you resolve it? is there a way to access the result from the after(:suite) ?

Comment: Hi Steven, I wasn't able to find a way yet

Answer (score 1):

Ugh.  I loathe rspec for making this not easy/obvious.  This is not what you're asking for, but it's an obvious framework:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    example.run # travel_to gets undone once we're back here - as opposed to around(:each)
  ensure
    RspecExecutiontimeRecorder.record(example)
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
    RspecExecutiontimeRecorder.report
  end
  ...
end
```

```
class RspecExecutiontimeRecorder
  include Singleton

  Record = Struct.new(:full_description, :file_path, :location, :duration)

  class << self
    def record(example)
      instance.record(example)
    end

    def report
      instance.report
    end
  end

  def initialize
    @records = []
  end

  def record(example)
    # Because this callback is part of the example, we don't have an end/run time - so we make it up
    duration = Time.now - example.metadata[:execution_result].started_at
    metadata = example.metadata
    @records << Record.new(metadata[:full_description], metadata[:file_path], metadata[:location], duration)
  end

  def report
    pp @records
  end
end
```

You could just record the metadata for each and then parse it at the end, but maybe that becomes a LOT of data?  I'm just interested in the little timing bits so that's all I store.